# Software for multiple logistic regression analysis

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, software

Which free and easy to use statistical software can I use to perform a multiple logistic regression analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JASP.](https://jasp-stats.org/) It is a graphical user interface that is pretty user-friendly and runs the R programming language underneath. There are lots of tutorials online for this and a dedicated community that keeps it running.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this.